# Docker 1.12 Swarm Nodes IP's

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

Is there a way how I could get IPs of nodes joined in cluster?

In "old" swarm there is command that you can run on manager machine. `docker exec -it <containerid> /swarm list consul://x.x.x.x:8500`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see a list of nodes, use:

```
docker node ls
```

Unfortunately they don't include IP's and ports in this output. You can run a `docker node inspect $hostname` on each one to get it's swarm ip/port. Then if you need to add more nodes to your cluster, you can use `docker swarm join-token worker` which does include the needed IP/port in it's output.

What `docker node ls` does provide is hostnames of each node in your swarm cluster. Unlike the standalone swarm, you do not connect your docker client directly to the swarm port. You now access it from one of the manager hosts in the same way you'd connect to that host before to init/join the swarm. After connecting to one of the manager hosts, you use `docker service` commands to control your running services.

Comment: If you inspect node that is a worker. You still don't get IP. You only get IP of master node.

Comment: Interesting, but there's no end user value of the worker ip/port for docker, you can't connect to it the way you did with the standalone swarm version, so I guess they didn't see a reason to expose it. More than likely, that port and ip are not fixed in docker, only the hostname and the certificate are needed for the worker to connect to the manager and wait for jobs.